# Only return the NumberOfFeatures in a WFS query

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I'm running a GetFeature WFS query in GeoServer (looking for features within a polygon) but all I actually want is the total number of features. Is there a way of just returning this info (in the hope that the query will run a little faster) rather than all the records?

The query is returning over 10,000 features so I hope it would make a difference if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the parameter resultType to "hits" and you will get the number of features in the query similar to the count() function in SQL.

HTTP Get request example:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&version=1.1.0&resultType=hits
```

HTTP Post request example with a filter:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  resultType="hits"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                      http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states">
    <ogc:Filter>
       <ogc:FeatureId fid="states.3"/>
    </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: Thanks taudorf - that worked a treat. Interestingly, the search time (running the search directly in geoserver) took 18 seconds - as oppose to 41 seconds when returning just one field per feature.

Answer (score 5):

Provided you are using WFS 1.1 you can set resultype=hits and this will return just the number of records that match your query.

I can't recall if GeoServer has back ported this to 1.0 but the standard doesn't support it.